# How to apply chaining-associativity in C++17

Tags: c++, math, functional-programming, c++17

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  vector<int> v1{1,2,3};
  vector<int> v2{3,2,1};
  vector<int> v3{3,2,1,2};

  int increasing = reduce(v1.begin(), v1.end(), 1, less<int>());
  for_each(v1.begin(), v1.end(),[](int &k){cout<< k <<",";});
  cout << " Increasing? " << increasing << endl;

  increasing = reduce(v2.begin(), v2.end(), 1, less<int>());
  for_each(v2.begin(), v2.end(),[](int &k){cout<< k <<",";});
  cout << " Increasing? " << increasing << endl;

  increasing = reduce(v3.begin(), v3.end(), 1, less<int>());
  for_each(v3.begin(), v3.end(),[](int &k){cout<< k <<",";});
  cout << " Increasing? " << increasing << endl;
}
```

In this example I test the vectors if all of their elements are increasing or not and here are the results:

```
1,2,3, Increasing? 1
3,2,1, Increasing? 0
3,2,1,2, Increasing? 0
```

The vectors `v1` and `v2` pass the tests correctly but the `v3` doesn't  because the `less<int>` function is applied by default as *left-associative* i.e. it is applied to the element on the left only.

To test the `v3` correctly, the `less<int>` function should be applied to the vector as a whole and AFAIK that is achieved by the so-called *chaining-associativity*.

Note that I'm not merely trying to check for a sorted sequence. I'm looking for a way to implement this so-called *chaining-associativity* for any function and here for the sake of example it is the `less<int>`.

So I'd like to apply the `less<int>` as *chaining-associative* in a concise manner i.e. without messing up the code. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use `std::is_sorted()`?

Comment: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce): *"`reduce` behaves like `std::accumulate` except the elements of the range may be grouped and rearranged in arbitrary order"*. So you cannot use that function.

Comment: And even `std::accumulate` won't test the right thing, it would return `(((v[0] < v[1]) < v[2]) < v[3])`.

Comment: @Shawn Thank you for the comment. Well I'd still like to apply the chaining-associativity to `less<int>` The rationale is because I'd like to apply *any* function to a sequence, other than sorting.

Comment: @Jarod42 Well, basically I'm looking for a way to apply `chain-associativity` whether it be with the `reduce` or `accumulate` Any way of doing it is ok as long as it is concise.

Comment: All of [std::is_sorted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted), [std::is_sorted_until](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted_until), [std::adjacent_find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) take predicate that you can adjust to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my first suggestion to use `std::is_sorted()` wouldn't work in the case of two adjacent elements with the same value - they're sorted, but not increasing. But if you want to use standard algorithms and not do it with a hand-written loop, `std::adjacent_find()` works:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Version using an explicit binary predicate
template <class It, class F>
bool increasing(const It beg, const It end, F op) {
  return std::adjacent_find(beg, end, [&op](const auto &a, const auto &b) {
           return !op(a, b);
         }) == end;
}

// Version using <
template <class It> bool increasing(const It beg, const It end) {
  return std::adjacent_find(beg, end, [](const auto &a, const auto &b) {
           return !(a < b);
         }) == end;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v1{1, 2, 3}, v2{3, 2, 1}, v3{3, 2, 1, 2};

  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << "v1 increasing: " << increasing(v1.begin(), v1.end()) << '\n';
  std::cout << "v2 increasing: "
            << increasing(v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::less<int>()) << '\n';
  std::cout << "v3 increasing: " << increasing(v3.begin(), v3.end()) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

gives

```
v1 increasing: true
v2 increasing: false
v3 increasing: false
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort. The version using `<` looks and works quite fine. I'll make use of it.